# Delete single values from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a program that stores a lot of values in `file.txt`. I want to be able to delete some value (like 1 value per minute) from the file. (For the storing method I store 1 value per line if it is helpful.)

There is a semi-solution creating a second file but my problem is that my program has to keep storing data in the `file.txt`, then has to delete some data from the same `file.txt`.

I also have to stop the program sometimes, and I don't want to lose my data by putting it in a string.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: You can read your data into a list, filter (delete the desired data), and then overwrite the file with the joined values of the final list.

Comment: Have you considered using a simple database, e.g. SQLite, instead?

Comment: Another even simpler alternative is [tinydb](https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb) which is implented in pure python. It stores your data in a plain json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name = 'values' # Change to whatever your file is called
directory = '' # Change to your directory (inside a folder etc.:). Leave blank if none
filetype = '.txt' # Change to your file type

data = []
repeat = 0


with open(directory+name+filetype,'r') as file: # Gets data from file
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split('\n'):
            if repeat % 2 == 0: # Doesn't add every other term, which are empty strings
                data.append(word)
            repeat += 1

del data[0] # Change to delete whatever item of your list

file = open(directory+name+filetype,"w") # Opens and clears the file

for values in data: # Writes to file
    file.write(values + '\n')

file.close() # Closes the file
```

Comment: What's the point of `try: open(...) except: pass` Firstly, that is a seriously janky way of clearing a file, but why do it in the first place if you go on to open the same exact file anyway?

Comment: I was trying to show the OP what everything does, but I do agree with you. I will edit it now

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, this works perfectly but i didn't understand what 'repeat' does

Comment: When you split the line, for word in line.split('\n') every other value is just '' which you don't want to add to the list so you ignore them. The modulo operator (%) finds the reminder when dividing by a number. So it acts like filtering out every other term with the code I have, as 1%2 = 1 so you ignore it. The next tern 2%2 = 0 so you add it to the list etc.:.